# How to add a default null row if no results from the dynamic pivot query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I execute this procedure and display results in my application. If my query does not return any results, I still need to print out the column headers and since its a dynamic query I cannot hard code. My query runs fine, Its just how do I add a NULL row if not results are found. So for instance  in a scenario where this is the result of executing the SP, SQL returns the column headers, I'd like to add a null row.

TSBNumber System1 System2 System3

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spExportServiceTSB]                            
    (@StartDate datetime,                            
    @EndDate datetime,                                   
    @SelectedSystemIDs nvarchar (2000) = NULL,    
    @SelectedTsbIDs nvarchar (2000) = NULL,   
    @UserRoleID int
    )                            
    AS  



DECLARE @PlatformID INT = NULL

IF(@SelectedSystemIDs = '')
BEGIN
SET @SelectedSystemIDs = NULL
END

IF(@SelectedTsbIDs = '')
BEGIN
SET @SelectedTsbIDs = '0'
END

IF(@UserRoleID = 1)    
 BEGIN     
  SET @PlatformID = 1     
  END  

IF(@UserRoleID = 2)  
BEGIN  
SET @PlatformID = 2  
END  

IF (@UserRoleID = 3)    
BEGIN    
SET @PlatformID = 12    
END   

IF(@UserRoleID = 4)
BEGIN 
SET @PlatformID = 3
END

IF(@UserRoleID = 5)
BEGIN 
SET @PlatformID = 4
END

IF(@UserRoleID = 6)
BEGIN 
SET @PlatformID = 0
END

DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =  
   COALESCE(
     @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' +  cast(SystemFullName as Nvarchar) + ']',
     '[' + cast(SystemFullName as varchar)+ ']'
   )
FROM System 
WHERE (@SelectedSystemIDs IS NULL OR  System.ID IN(select  * from dbo.SplitInts_RBAR_1(@SelectedSystemIDs, ',')))     
AND ((@PlatformID =0) OR  (System.PlatformID = @PlatformID) OR (@PlatformID = 12 AND System.PlatformID <= 2))  

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
   SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT
       TSBNumber [TSBNumber],
       SystemFullName,
       ClosedDate
     FROM ServiceEntry 
     INNER JOIN System 
       ON ServiceEntry.SystemID = System.ID
     where
      (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber IS NOT NULL)
       AND 
       (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL)
       AND
       ( 
       (''' + @SelectedTsbIDs + ''' = '''+ '0' + ''') OR
         (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber in (select * from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(''' + @SelectedTsbIDs + ''', ''' + ',' + ''')))
        )  
        AND (
         (''' + CAST(@PlatformID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''' = '''+ '0' + ''') 
        OR(System.PlatformID = ''' + cast(@PlatformID as varchar(10)) + ''')
        OR(''' + CAST(@PlatformID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''' = ''' + '12' + ''' AND System.PlatformID <=  ''' + '2' + ''')
        )
        AND
        (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate between ''' + convert(varchar(10), @StartDate, 120)  + '''  and   ''' +  convert(varchar(10), @EndDate, 120) + ''')

   ) AS PivotData
   PIVOT (
     MAX(ClosedDate)
     FOR SystemFullName IN (
       ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
     ) 
   ) AS PivotTable
' 



EXECUTE (@PivotTableSQL)
```

To resolve the above issue I tried to add a null row by doing a UNION all but getting this error. I am now trying to add a null row so the revised query is as follows

```
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.


   SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT
       TSBNumber [TSBNumber],
       SystemFullName,
       ClosedDate
     FROM ServiceEntry 
     inner JOIN System 
       ON ServiceEntry.SystemID = System.ID
     where
      (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber IS NOT NULL)
       AND 
       (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL)
       AND
       ( 
       ('145' = '0') OR
         (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber in (select * from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden('145', ',')))
        )  
        AND (
         ('1' = '0') 
        OR(System.PlatformID = '1')
        OR('1' = '12' AND System.PlatformID <=  '2')
        )
        AND
        (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate between '2014-09-29'  and   '2014-10-06')    


  UNION ALL 

  select
    NULL, ''
where NOT EXISTS( 

 SELECT
       TSBNumber [TSBNumber],
       SystemFullName,
       ClosedDate
     FROM ServiceEntry 
     inner JOIN System 
       ON ServiceEntry.SystemID = System.ID
     where
      (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber IS NOT NULL)
       AND 
       (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL)
       AND
       ( 
       ('145' = '0') OR
         (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber in (select * from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden('145', ',')))
        )  
        AND (
         ('1' = '0') 
        OR(System.PlatformID = '1')
        OR('1' = '12' AND System.PlatformID <=  '2')
        )
        AND
        (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate between '2014-09-29'  and   '2014-10-06')   



  )

   ) AS PivotData
   PIVOT (
     MAX(ClosedDate)
     FOR SystemFullName IN (
       [EP(+)12  -  A20 - 107D],[EP(+)13  -  AP20 109B],[EP(+)14  -  AP20 -407A]
     ) 
   ) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Even if there are no rows, a result set with defined columns is still returned to your application. Your application should be displaying the column headers even if there are no rows.

Comment: well im using .NET and utility called dapper for dynamic columns. if the query is just returning defined columns the object in the application is empty. I am trying to basically do a UNION all to add null row but getting some errors All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
  UNION ALL 
  
  select
    NULL, ''
where NOT EXISTS

Comment: Why was this closed? Just because some moderator found it too specific? It matched my Google search nearly precisely. Unless you can provide a decent answer, quit closing questions just because they are not in your wheelhouse.

Answer (score 5):

Use your original query as a derived table and outer-join it to a dummy row, referencing only the query's columns in the main SELECT:

```
SELECT
  q.*
FROM
  (SELECT NULL) AS d (dummy)
LEFT JOIN
  (
    your query
  ) AS q
ON
  1 = 1
;
```

This is almost like a cross join with a single row, except in this case the final output will always have at least one row. If the subquery does not return any rows, its columns will be null in the output.

Comment: So in my original query, I should remove my inner join?

Comment: @user48768: By your original query I meant the one you want (and have been trying) to append an empty row to. That is, the entire PIVOT query would be the *`your query`* in the above suggestion.

Comment: Great idea. Also helpful if you need a default (status for example), i'm doing it like so (Oracle):
`SELECT nvl(q.s, hlp.s)
FROM (SELECT 'b' s FROM dual) hlp
LEFT JOIN (SELECT s FROME stuff WHERE id = ?
) q ON 1 = 1;`